# Dynamic Where Clause T-SQL varibable operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I am trying to set my where condition in my sql based on an input variable to a stored procedure.

```
Where RF.InternalCompany = @Company  
And RF.Installdate between @Datefrom  and @DateTo
AND CASE WHEN @ContractType = 'Single Asset Contract' THEN numA.NumOfAssets = 1 
    WHEN @ContractType = 'Multi-Asset Contract' THEN numA.NumOfAssets > 1
    END
```

How do I set this?

Comment: Are you trying to _set_ a variable here, or are you trying to _use_ that variable in the logic of the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND 
(
    ( @ContractType = 'Single Asset Contract' AND numA.NumOfAssets = 1 )
    OR 
    ( @ContractType = 'Multi-Asset Contract'  AND numA.NumOfAssets > 1 )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it like below..

```
Where RF.InternalCompany = @Company  
And RF.Installdate between @Datefrom  and @DateTo
AND ((@ContractType = 'Single Asset Contract' AND     numA.NumOfAssets = 1 ) Or 
(@ContractType = 'Multi-Asset Contract' AND numA.NumOfAssets > 1))
```